# Find and replace sepecific text in Excel Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I Have a cell A2 in Excel with:

> BenQ ZOWIE XL2411P 24" LED 144Hz e-Sports

[image: BenQ ZOWIE XL2411P 24" LED 144Hz e-Sports]

I want extract phrases and transform them.

If text contain "LED" so write "Display: LED | ". If text contain  "144Hz" so write "Refresh Rate: 144Hz | ". How can I do it with one function in one cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions for this

eg, if your text is in `A1`, then use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"LED","Display: LED"),"144Hz","Refresh Rate: 144Hz")
```

<sub>Note that this will find the search terms imbeded within other terms. Eg if you already had `...Display: LED...` in your string, this will return `...Display: Display: LED...`</sub>

Comment: Almost worked, thanks, Its returning: BenQ ZOWIE XL2411P 24" Display: LED Refresh Rate: 144Hz e-Sports and I need only: Dysplay: LED | Refresh Rate: 144Hz

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "I want extract phrases and transform them." But I would think you could do something similar to displaying the result by using the ampersand. From the examples you might be able to use

IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("LED",A2)),"Display: LED |")&" "&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("144Hz",A2)),"Refresh Rate: 144Hz |")

Though I can't verify that will work right now.

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-create-multiple-formulas-for-the-same-space-in-excel
https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/contains-specific-text.html